# Inequalities solver using prolog

Tags: prolog, clpq

I am new to Prolog and inequalities.I want to solve following type of inequality question using Prolog. I am using SWI-Prolog.

eg: 2x+3>5 is the question.How can I write a program to get the answer of this program x>1.

Answer (score 2):

It is not quite clear what you want, but you might want to solve these equations in the rationals. In this case, `library(clpq)` might be interesting to you. Below is running in SWI 6.

```
?- use_module(library(clpq)).
% library(clpq) compiled into clpq 0.25 sec, 2,727 clauses
true.

?- {2*X+3>5}.
{X>1}.
```

Comment: thnks.It worked.I want to get this answer through .pl file.So i need kind of prolog coding for that.That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Not sure what you want, but first, consult the manual on CLPQ.

Comment: well,what you have given can run directly via prolog compiler.But i need to do coding on a pl file and then compile it.So I need to solve above type of question by identifying left hands side and right hand side seperately .likewise.

Answer (score -1):

Try the not() condition

not(2x+3 = 5)